# PosgreSQL - column referece is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get a number of units per room. I have two separate tables rooms and units. Room can be only one, but can have multiple units. I am trying to get a list of rooms with number of units for each. This is even if there are 0 units in given room. I worked to the point I wanted to print in the table also the room_id. room_id figures both in room table and unit table. Therefore I am getting error message stating that room_id is ambiguous. Of course I would expect this to understand that I want room_id from the room table.

I have following query:

```
SELECT count(ucr.*) units_no
, ucr.room_name
, ucr.room_image
, ucr.room_id
FROM (
SELECT u.*
, r.room_image
, r.room_name
, r.room_id
FROM unit u
LEFT JOIN room r ON r.room_id = u.room_id
WHERE r.room_id = 'b6229c33-a37e-4457-8fb0-941d632c2540'
) ucr
GROUP BY ucr.room_name, ucr.room_image, ucr.room_id;
```

I am getting following error:
`column reference "room_id" is ambiguous`

I have tried following:
`, ucr.r.room_id`

Also following:
`, ucr(r.room_id)`

Also following:
`, ucr.(r.room_id)`

I run out of options. How do I do this? Thank you for taking your time having a look on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unit` and `room` tables both have a column called `room_id`.  Therefore, the inner select is ambiguous:

```
SELECT u.*, r.room_image, r.room_name, r.room_id
```

because it isn't clear *which* `room_id` value to use in the outer query.  You could alias the two `room_id` columns to unique names, but given that your query doesn't even seem to need the columns from the `unit` table, I would suggest:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(ucr.room_name) units_no,
       ucr.room_name,
       ucr.room_image,
       ucr.room_id
FROM (
    SELECT r.room_image, r.room_name, r.room_id
    FROM unit u
    LEFT JOIN room r ON r.room_id = u.room_id
    WHERE r.room_id = 'b6229c33-a37e-4457-8fb0-941d632c2540'
) ucr
GROUP BY ucr.room_name, ucr.room_image, ucr.room_id;
```

Actually, the subquery itself seems unnecessary and we can just use:

```sql
SELECT r.room_image, r.room_name, r.room_id, COUNT(*) AS units_no
FROM unit u
LEFT JOIN room r
    ON r.room_id = u.room_id AND
       r.room_id = 'b6229c33-a37e-4457-8fb0-941d632c2540'
GROUP BY r.room_image, r.room_name, r.room_id;
```

Comment: I like the simplified version, but it won't return room with 0 units in it, and I need to list all of them including those that don't have any units added yet.

Comment: ...it does now, check the edit.  Just move the restriction from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the left join.

Comment: wow it really does, what if I would want to show all rooms by account_id - so change the r.room_id = '...' to `r.account_id = '244edbb1-2880-444c-be13-0f515b869923'` In that case I do get unit count but I don't get the other data

Comment: I can't answer this comment without seeing your data.

Comment: Sure. What do you exactly need to be able to asses this?

Comment: SELECT count(ucr.*) units_no
, ucr.room_name
, ucr.room_image
, ucr.rooom_id
FROM (
SELECT u.*
, r.room_image
, r.room_name
, r.room_id as rooom_id
FROM unit u
LEFT JOIN room r ON r.room_id = u.room_id
WHERE u.account_id = '244edbb1-2880-444c-be13-0f515b869923'
) ucr
GROUP BY ucr.room_name, ucr.room_image, ucr.rooom_id; This will return but only rooms that have any units on them.

Comment: Can't say for certain, because again I can't see your data.  Try moving the restriction on `account_id` to the join `ON` condition.